# Восстановление 3д изображения по двум стереоснимкам

Tags: c#, 3d, matlab

Есть 2 стереоснимка, мне по ним нужно получить облако точек (т.е. 3д изображение). Алгоритм для этого нашел, но вот как правильно это сделать, в упор не понимаю, возможно где то ошибка...
каждый раз получаю ошибки в изображении. облако точек строю с помощью матлаб.

вот и алгоритм
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/09wi/Lects/lect16.pdf

Comment: спрашиваю чисто для общего развития: а как имея **только** 2 снимка вы решаете обе главные проблемы:
1)узнать фокусное(камеры) и базовое(между снимками) расстояния?
2)поиск соответствия между множествами точек снимков?

Да и смотря что за ошибки в изображении, может это общее искажение из-за неверного заданного фокусного/базового расстояния? или из-за того, что оптические оси вы зря считали абсолютно параллельными? это множество "вылетов" из-за точек(их исключать?), которым на втором снимке не нашлось соответствия?

расскажите, интересно  :-)

Comment: В статье как раз об этом и говорится, что фокусное расстояние необходимо знать, иначе ничего не получится, ну или получится с искажениями, по поводу оптических осей - обязаны быть параллельны (см. схему стереоскопической системы). Вот насчет вылетов главная проблема, думаю стоит вводить дополнительные параметры, типа освещения бинарного или последовательность де Брёйна. Если нужно могу код на с# кинуть...